# Why on a file new project can I not get child subitems working in NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

I am trying to have child items below items in the Navigation view am looking at the win ui 3 gallary example but it uses the navigationstore I dont need to use that as its small navigation.

But when I attempt to use this code.

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="MyNavigationView">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Icon="Home"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Favorites" Icon="Favorite">
           
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Favorites" Icon="Favorite">
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Item 1"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Item 2"/>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <!-- Add more parent items with child items here -->
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```

The compiler complains about this line.

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="Item 1"/>
```

I get

```
   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XLS0501 The property 'Content' is set more than once.   Cella.WinUi D:\GitMaster\Cella\Cella.WinUi\MainWindow.xaml  18
```

Does anybody know why this is happening also should I be even using win ui it almost feels dead at present. Or should I use UWP.

https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery

I am wanting to achieve this the sub items under the main menu text.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing my nesting wrong this seems to work fine now.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="MyNavigationView">
      <NavigationView.MenuItems>
          <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Icon="Home"/>
          <NavigationViewItem Content="Favorites" Icon="Favorite">
         
          </NavigationViewItem>

          <NavigationViewItem
              x:Name="SalesOrder"
              Content="WMS"
              Tag="WMS">
              <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                  <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEB3C;" />
              </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
              <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                  <NavigationViewItem x:Name="CreateSalesOrder" Content="Create Sales Order" Tag="CreateSalesOrder">
                      <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                          <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE8D2;" />
                      </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                  </NavigationViewItem>
                  <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SalesORDERs" Content="Sales Orders" Tag="SalesORDERs">
                      <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                          <FontIcon Glyph="&#xED58;" />
                      </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                  </NavigationViewItem>
                  <NavigationViewItem x:Name="SalesI" Content="Sales Invoice" Tag="SalesI">
                      <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                          <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE790;" />
                      </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                  </NavigationViewItem>
                  
              </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
          </NavigationViewItem>

          <!-- Add more parent items with child items here -->
      </NavigationView.MenuItems>
  </NavigationView>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you've found a solution. You could accept your answer and this could help others who are facing the same issue.